# How to use NestJS-i18n with an Excel file instead of JSON file?

Tags: excel, nestjs

I'm trying to use NestJS-i18n for internationalization in my NestJS application. Currently, I have all my translation keys and values stored in a JSON file. However, I have a requirement to switch to an Excel file for managing translations.

I've been searching for a way to do this, but I haven't found any documentation or examples on how to use an Excel file with NestJS-i18n.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how I could achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your excel file to Json using `xlsx` package:

here enter code hereis an example of parser:

use `sheet_to_json` method for parsing xcell to json

| Key | en | fr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| greeting | Hello | Bonjour |
| welcome_message | Welcome to | Bienvenue à |

```js
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';

export class ExcelParser {
  constructor(private readonly options: ExcelParserOptions) {}

  async parse(): Promise<Record<string, any>> {
    const workbook = xlsx.readFile(this.options.path);
    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[this.options.sheetName];

    const data : any[]  = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 1,
      raw: false,
    });

    const keys = data[0].slice(1);
    const translations = {};

    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      const row = data[i];
      const key = row[0];

      translations[key] = {};

      for (let j = 1; j < keys.length + 1; j++) {
        const language = keys[j - 1];
        const value = row[j];

        translations[key][language] = value;
      }
    }

    return translations;
  }

}

export interface ExcelParserOptions {
  path: string;
  sheetName: string;
}
```